# Idangerous swiper flexible height of container

Tags: jquery, css, height

Ive been looking around and seems this only bothers me.
I have a site for testing swiper [here](http://design.imago.ee/test/swiper/17-responsive2.html):

I would like to swiper container height to be flexible depending on the current slide,
right now i have 2 images with heights of 900px and 300px. Its setting the wrapper height to
900px and i could not change it. I tried height auto important and swiper api options.

> So my question is: Is there a way to set the swiper container height to flexible depending on the slide which is currently active?